# IOS version and retina support

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the cut off for iOS version where I can say everything is Retina Display and I don't need to worry about the 1x images anymore? I want to say anything iOS 8 or newer is going to be Retina Display, but does it goes back further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is iPhone only, then iOS 7.

However for universal apps, iPad 2 and mini are still supported even by iOS 9.

Comment: Ok, so the answer we still need 1x, 2x and now 3x.  Thanks!

Comment: if you support iPad correct. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. (And close the question)

Comment: I will accept, it says I have to wait 10 mins before accepting